# How to execute the RPS according to the Ultimate thread group configurations excluding startup and shutdown time?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

**I need to run load test for few API calls with below configurations for 8 hours. I have few confusions(mentioned as questions)**

[Ultimate Thread Group Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNs8H.jpg)

| Start Threads Count | Initial Delay,Sec | Startup Time | Hold Load For, Sec | ShutDown Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 0 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 65 | 3600 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 80 | 7200 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 95 | 10800 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 110 | 14400 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 125 | 18000 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 140 | 21600 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |
| 155 | 25200 | 300 | 3000 | 300 |

[Shapping timer configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prl7g.jpg)

| Start RPS | End RPS | Duration,Sec |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 3000 |
| 4 | 4 | 3000 |
| 5 | 5 | 3000 |
| 6 | 6 | 3000 |
| 7 | 7 | 3000 |
| 8 | 8 | 3000 |
| 9 | 9 | 3000 |
| 10 | 10 | 3000 |

**Expected Requests per hour basis**

| Expected Requests |
| --- |
| 9000 |
| 12000 |
| 15000 |
| 18000 |
| 21000 |
| 24000 |
| 27000 |
| 30000 |

**Understanding regarding above configurations**

Overall goal is to perform a load test with small no of RPS for 8 hours(RPS will be increase in 2nd run for 8 hours that configuration is not mentioned here) by increasing 15 users in each hour by startup time of 5mint(300Sec) and than hold load for 50mints each hour and than shutdown within 5mints(300Sec) and so on.

**Questions:**

1. Are these configurations are correct.
2. RPS will be generated between startup and shutdown time means only for hold load duration?
3. How to generate a graph or table view for requests per hour basis(How much requests generated within first, second hour and so on) with no of active threads for each hour?

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know as it's unclear how many requests per second you're trying to conduct with how how many users for each moment of the test.
2. If you want to exclude some results from the report you can either use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)
3. There is [Transaction Throughput vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/) listener which generates the chart with RPS vs number of active users

Both Filter Results Tool and Transaction Throughput vs Threads are plugins which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: for 1st hour 50 users and 3RPS and for 2nd hour 65 users with 4 RPS and so on and i have mentioned the expected no of requests per hour as well. If still not clear please let me know.

Comment: In that case configuration is correct